# ayuda con DtaTable y row child

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, mvc

amigos estoy queriendo implementar el datatable con su row child como se muestra en el siguiente link, pero tengo un problema

https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html

mi código es el siguiente la tabla  es el siguiente.

```
<table id="tabla-ofertas" class="font-light table display nowrap table-striped">
      <thead>
          <tr class="text-center">
            <th>No.</th>
            <th>Marcas</th>
            <th>Licitante</th>
            <th>Partida<br />Clave</th>
            <th>Precio <br />Ofertado</th>
            <th>Descuento<br />Ofertado</th>
            <th>Cantidad <br />Máxima</th>
            <th>Cantidad <br />Minima</th>
            <th>Monto <br />Partida</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<tbody>

    @{          
        int status = 1;
    }

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td class="text-center">@(status++)</td>                
            <td orderid="@item.MtoOfertaId" class="details-control"></td>
            <td>@item.MtoProveedor.RazonSocial</td>
            <td class="text-justify">
                <span class="text-success">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MtoRequerimiento.Partida)
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MtoRequerimiento.Gpo)
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MtoRequerimiento.Gen)
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MtoRequerimiento.Esp)
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MtoRequerimiento.Dif)
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MtoRequerimiento.Var)
                </span> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MtoRequerimiento.Descripcion)
            </td>

            <td class="text-right">@item.PrecioOfertado.ToString("C") </td>
            <td class="text-right">@item.Descuento.ToString("N") </td>
            <td class="text-right">@item.MaximoOfertado.ToString("N0")</td>
            <td class="text-right">@item.MinimoOfertado.ToString("N0") </td>
            <td class="text-right">@item.MontoPartida.ToString("C") </td>
            <td>

                <div class="btn-group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        <i class="ti-settings"></i>
                    </button>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" x-placement="bottom-start" style="position: absolute; transform: translate3d(0px, 35px, 0px); top: 0px; left: 0px; will-change: transform;">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href='@Url.Action("Details", "Ofertas", new { @id = @item.MtoOfertaId })' title="Detalle">Detalle</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        @if (User.IsInRole("Admin") || User.IsInRole("SuperAdmin"))
                        {
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href='@Url.Action("Edit", "Ofertas", new { @id = @item.MtoOfertaId })' title="Editar Información"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>Editar</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="sweetDelete(id=@item.MtoOfertaId)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>Eliminar</a>

                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </td>
        </tr>      
    }


</tbody>
```

y el script con el que quiero implementar que se visualice el row child es el siguiente.

```
  @section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render(
       "~/Content/AdminElegant/assets/node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js",
       "~/Content/AdminElegant/assets/node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js",
       "~/Scripts/WebScript/MtoOferta.js")
<script>
        var table = $('#tabla-ofertas_wrapper')
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var table = $('#tabla-ofertas').DataTable();

            //$('#tabla-ofertas').on('click', 'tbody td.details-control', function () {
            $('body').on('click', '#tabla-ofertas tbody td.details-control', function () {

                var orderid = $(this).attr("orderid");

                var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                var row = table.row(tr);

                console.log("orderid: " + orderid);
                console.log("tr: " + tr);
                console.log("row: " + row);
                console.log("table: " + table);


                if (row.child.isShown()) {
                    // This row is already open - close it
                    row.child.hide();
                    tr.removeClass('shown');
                }
                else {
                    // Open this row
                    row.child(format(orderid)).show();
                    tr.addClass('shown');
                }

            });

        });

        function format(d) {

            $.get("@Url.Content("~/Generic/GetDetalleOfertaTecnicoEconomica")" + "?id=" + d, function (resultado) {
                console.log(resultado);
                        if (resultado == "false") {
                            carga = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $("#demo-test-gallery").append(resultado);
                            carga = false;
                        }
                    });
        }




</script>
```

el error que me muestra y que no he podido solucionar es

```
Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "show", row.child(...) is undefined
```

y es en la linea

```
 **row.child(format(orderid)).show();**
```

la verdad no se a que se deba, no omito mencionar que los estilos los agrego en el layout principal

espero puedan ayudarme.

gracias